# Unable to use web config transforms with securitySwitch. Possible workarounds?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, web-config-transform, securityswitch

I'm using [securitySwitch](https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/) for a few of my projects and it's worked wonderfully. However, one of my projects has grown and I'm unable to perform any web.config transforms on the securitySwitch config section.

So, in my web.config, I have the following:

```
<securitySwitch baseInsecureUri="uriWebsite1insecure" baseSecureUri="uriWebsite1secure" bypassSecurityWarning="true" mode="RemoteOnly" xmlns="http://SecuritySwitch-v4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SecuritySwitch-v4.xsd">
<paths>
  <add path="~/" ignoreCase="true" />
</paths>
</securitySwitch>
```

However, in one of my web.config transforms I need to change the baseInsecureUri and baseSecureUri to point to a different website:

```
<securitySwitch baseInsecureUri="uriWebsite2insecure" baseSecureUri="uriWebsite2secure" bypassSecurityWarning="true" mode="RemoteOnly"  xmlns="http://SecuritySwitch-v4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SecuritySwitch-v4.xsd" xdt:Transform="Replace">
<paths>
  <add path="~/" ignoreCase="true" />
</paths>
</securitySwitch>
```

It gives the following error: The http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Transform attribute is not declared.

I'm looking for any possible solution, even if it's not a "clean" one.

Thank you for your time!
- Andrew

Comment: Does it work with a pure webconfig without transformation?

Comment: It works fine without the transform. Basically, without transform I'm publishing it to WebsiteA. However, if the build is for WebsiteB then web.WebsiteB.config would transform that particular section. Everything else in web.WebsiteB.config work fine, but the securitySwitch section in it throws the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the namespace declaration on the SecuritySwitch section. This should fix it.

```
<securitySwitch baseInsecureUri="uriWebsite2insecure" baseSecureUri="uriWebsite2secure" bypassSecurityWarning="true" mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <paths>
    <add path="~/" ignoreCase="true" />
  </paths>
</securitySwitch>
```

Also, if all you need to do is change those two attributes, you can try this instead:

```
<securitySwitch baseInsecureUri="uriWebsite2insecure" baseSecureUri="uriWebsite2secure" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb. I could have sworn that I tried that but got some funky error. Nonetheless, I did as you suggested and successfully published without errors. Everything seems to be running as it should. Thank you.

Comment: The old library used to give a weird error with regards to the section schema, but I've since fixed it in the latest version of the library (4.x). Glad I could help!